# Laptop automatically forcing sound to mono when two programs try to output sound simultaneously

Tags: audio, drivers

I own a Acer Aspire VN7-591G (or Nitro black edition) running Windows 8.1 and, more often than not, I play video games while listening to music with iTunes. But there is a problem when doing so: my computer automatically forces one of these programs into a mono sound (normally the program which was launched later) while the other continues to play in normal stereo sound (which also seems to have a higher volume). What's bugging me though is that I cannot select which program runs in mono and also some programs (mostly the games) force themselves into stereo, which leads to iTunes playing in mono and with a really low volume.

My questions are:

- Why does that happen? Which program/driver could be responsible for that, or is this a Windows issue or specific to my laptop?
- Is it possible to disable this, or, if not, to decide manually which program has a stereo/mono output?

I hope that someone has a solution to this problem, and if more information is required, please tell me.